# Как заменить класс CertificateRequest на Windows Crypto API в генераторе сертификатов?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, x509certificate, cryptoapi

Мы сделали генератор сертификатов для нашего сервера и планируем встроить его в инсталлятор, чтобы всё происходило автоматически.

Для генерации сертификатов используется класс .NET Framework `CertificateRequest`. С помощью него можно сгенерировать сертификат сервера, подписанный сертификатом нашего НИИ, вшитого в программу. Главное, что меня сейчас не устраивает в получившейся программе - это её системные требования. Сам сервер сделан на .NET Framework 4.0, совместимом с Windows XP, которая кое-где у нас стоит, а класс `CertificateRequest` появился только в .NET Framework 4.7.2, который несовместим с Windows XP. Мне не нравится, что такая вспомогательная вещь имеет более высокие системные требования, чем основной продукт, при том, что для этого нет объективных причин. То, что мы не осилили ничего сложнее, чем класс `CertificateRequest`, - это субъективная причина.

Я смотрю в сторону Windows CryptoAPI, но там слишком скупая документация относительно генерации сертификатов, в основном описана их установка. По идее, нам нужна функция `CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate`, но в документации отсутствуют примеры того, что нужно передавать ей в качестве параметров, которых целых 9. Кроме того, у самого сертификата должно быть несколько расширений, и вроде бы в CryptoAPI это поддерживается, но тоже описано как-то очень скупо, без примеров.

Для сертификата нам нужно задать:

- Subject с именем хоста, куда устанавливается сервер (именно из-за возможных разных хостов нам нужен генератор сертификатов)
- DNS с тем же именем хоста
- Ограничения: сертификат не является Certification Authority
- Использование ключа: цифровая подпись, проверка подлинности
- Улучшенный ключ: проверка подлинности сервера (Oid 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
- Идентификатор ключа субъекта - сгенерированный открытый ключ RSA
- Срок действия сертификата
- Серийный номер сертификата

При создании сертификат необходимо подписать корневым сертификатом нашего НИИ.

Существует .NET библиотека Pluralsight, которая использует CryptoAPI, кое-что можно посмотреть в ней, но она умеет генерировать только самоподписанные сертификаты, а не сертификаты, подписанные другим сертификатом.

Comment: Можно использовать openssl, он хорошо документирован. Но придется тащить с собой нативную длл

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно сделать всё в вашем приложении? Вы можете генерировать сертификаты во внешнем приложении? ИМХО, самый простой способ - вызывать `openssl` во внешних процессах. Например, вот так https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309

Comment: Не то, что бы оффтоп, но даже на баш уже [просочислось про проблемы XP](https://bash.im/quote/467295) с сертификатами. Похоже на театр безопасности: вы уделяете внимание вопросу как бы снизить требования к инсталлятору -- в то время как игнорируете огромную брешь рядом с этим местом. Криптография в самой XP (и это не только про корневые сертификаты речь) обновлялась так давно и вы так пристально ищете как можно более старые библиотеки -- что это слабый путь. Отчего просто не отключить шифрование для XP? Сразу будет видно проблему, его же и так по факту нет.

Comment: Я без хейта и негатива, если что.

Comment: @AK `Отчего просто не отключить шифрование для XP?` - вот, да

Comment: @Pak Uula, нам нужно, чтобы это делал инсталлятор. Но мы не умеем встраивать в инсталлятор программы, которым нужны какие-нибудь dll. Хотя не факт, что это сложно (wix)